# How to count clicks on the whole jPanel?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm looking for answer this question: how to count clicks on whole jPanel? Code below counts clicks only on the one pixel.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("Zapraszamy do klieknięcia");

        jButton1.setText("Algorytm przyrostowy");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(162, 162, 162)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(74, 74, 74)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 237, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jPanel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int clicks = evt.getClickCount();
        int x = evt.getX();
        int y = evt.getY();


        System.out.println("Kliknołeś");

        double x1, y1, x2, y2;
        System.out.println("Współrzędne x: "+ x + ", y: "+ y + " Kliknoles: " + clicks);

    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("Kliknołeś JBUTTon");
    }                                        

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Code below counts clicks only on the one pixel.

Actually no, it counts the number of clicks associated with the event.  For example, if the operating system reports it as a double click the value will be `2`.  Typically this is based on the delay between clicks, but is ultimately up to the OS.

[`MouseEvent.getClickCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29):

> ```
> Returns the number of mouse clicks associated with this event.
>
> Returns:
>    integer value for the number of clicks
> ```

Are you trying to track the number of clicks that have ever happened on the JPanel?  If so, I would add a mouse listener and keep a variable that increments with each click.

```
//instance variable somewhere
int clickCount = 0;

//after you create your panel
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
        clickCount++;
    }
});
```

### Edit

The [tutorial on writing Mouse Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) is also relevant:

> ```
> int getClickCount()
> ```
>
> Returns the number of quick, consecutive clicks the user has made (including this event). For example, returns 2 for a double click.

As this hints, Java does not aggregate consecutive clicks into a single event...if you receive a click event with `getClickCount()` equal to 1, that one click might still be the first click in the sequence of clicks representing a double click.

Comment: Except, if he truly want the total clicks, you need to add `getClickCount()` each time, not simply increment.

Comment: @Software: that's not actually true.  You get an event for each click, even if another is coming immediately after.  A double click sends an event for the first click with `getClickCount()==1`, and then another after with `getClickCount()==2`.  If he were to do as you say he would count 3 clicks total for a double click, not two.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct - I had forgotten about that.  Really annoying if you want discreet actions for single vs. double clicks.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an old question, but I came across this and it seems to be just what I am looking for--counting mouse clicks over a whole JPanel. However, when I try to add the MouseAdapter to the JPanel, I get a compile error saying that it is expecting a Component or PopupMenu, not a MouseAdapter. Does your example code actually work and maybe I am just doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Logan: Been a while since I've written any Swing code, but I think it likely should be `panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter...)`, not just `add`.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @LawrenceDol re discrete actions: I've never hit that problem: it's good form to ensure that a 1-click is on the path to the 2-click action (eg, 1-click selects an item if not selected (else ignore), 2-click activates or opens that item). This is easy to impl: clickCount==1 -> select; clickCount==2 -> open. If the single-click is orthogonal to the 2-click action (eg single->open item; double->delete item) then you'd only know to do the 1-click action once you'd waited long enough for the 2nd click without receiving it; nasty for the user if they fail to click fast enough too.